# Meaning of does not separate zero from infinity

Tags: banach-spaces, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

[In this excerpt](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=7_7xAAAAMAAJ&q=spectrum%20does%20not%20separate%20zero%20from%20infinity&dq=spectrum%20does%20not%20separate%20zero%20from%20infinity&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjnovPb14LwAhUCfSsKHSRECI4Q6AEwAXoECAQQAw), it states that
‘ Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator on a Banach space $X$. Suppose spectrum that the $\sigma(T)$ does not separate zero from infinity ( consequently the operator is invertible).’

I wanted to know what is the meaning of the term ‘does not separate zero from infinity’ and how does it imply that $T$ is invertible? An answer or a reference that uses this terminology will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Riemann sphere minus the spectrum, the points $0$ and $\infty$ are in the same connected component.  In particular, $0$ is not in the spectrum, so (by definition of *spectrum*) $T$ is invertible.